# Javascript to have a different background image of a div on refresh

Tags: css, refresh, background-image

Please, could you tell me why this JavaScript to have a different background image of a `div` on refresh is not working:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {    
        var thediv = document.getElementById("top");
        var imgarray = new Array("banner2.jpg", "banner3.jpg");
        var spot = Math.floor(Math.random()* imgarry.length);
        thediv.style.background = "url(images/header/banner/"+imgarray[spot]+")";
    }
</script>
</head>
```

The site can be seen at http://physoc.org.uk

Thanks.

Comment: Proper code formatting definitely helps. You have misspelled "imgarray" as "imgarry" on the line where you declare your `spot` variable.

Answer (score 0):

My Javascript console says:

```
Timestamp: 26.01.2013 17:00:19
Error: ReferenceError: imgarry is not defined
Source File: http://www.physoc.org.uk/
Line: 84
```

There's a typo in your code. You used "imgarry" instead of "imgarray" somewhere.

Press CTRL+SHIFT+J to open the console and see for yourself, works in Firefox and Chrome. It's very useful to debug Javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line. There is a `typo`

from

```
var spot = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgarry.length);
```

to

```
var spot = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgarray.length);
```

Comment: Thank you, I should have spotted that